# How can I repair a damaged aloe vera that hasn't been watered for months?

Tags: succulents, aloe, damage

One of my relatives gave me an aloe vera plant, but it was really damaged. I have cut the damaged parts (which were on the leaves), so I want to ask how to repair it to grow healthily once again.

I don't have soil right now so I put it into a water pot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a photo? It always helps us to look at photos. I will answer generically for now.

Aloes are sturdy, hardy plants. You have it in water, but don't leave it there for too long. Get good draining soil and plant it, mulch, and set the plant against bright, indirect light till the plant heals.

Do not feed the plant. Let it get roots and start growing first. The same way, after healing, you can move the plants out in the sun.

Comment: It hasn't been watered for nearly 5 or 6 months. As you can see its green color is lighter than usual and there are the remains of the damaged parts I cut

Comment: Did you upload a photo? I am not able to see it. Green and lighter is good. It means there is chance for recovery.

Comment: I don't know why it can't be uploaded, there is something wrong.

Comment: I have edited the question, and the image is attached.

Comment: This guy looks fine. Please follow my suggestions. Check back over the next few weeks.

Comment: I just put it couple hours ago in water, is that okay? Or I have to put it into soil urgently? And how long should I wait to water it after putting it?

Comment: No. Just make sure you get it out in a couple of hours or at most, a day. Any soil will do, but good, well draining, potting soil is best. You could lightly moist a paper towel and wrap the roots there till you get it into soil. Aloe doesn't need a lot of water. As a succulent, it is able to retain water in its leaves, and seeing from your photo, it already has plenty.